# Is it possible to use ActiveX controls in an SDI application (as opposed to a dialog-based application)?

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I'm new to MFC and ActiveX. I'm trying to use a 3rd party ActiveX control in my MFC application.

I successfully did it using a dialog-based MFC Application,
but it doesn't work if I select 'Single document' when creating a new MFC project(solution) in Visual Studio.

**1.** How can I use a 3rd-party ActiveX control if I want to create a 'single/multiple document' MFC application?

**2.** What is the idiomatic way to use 3rd-party ActiveX control with C++? (it's ok even if it's not MFC)

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: When you're using the *"MFC Application"* wizard to create a new MDI/SDI application, you'll find an *"ActiveX controls"* checkbox under *"Advanced Features"*. That should answer the question from the title. You can find an introduction to ActiveX controls [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/activex-controls). It's a complex topic that requires users to have a firm grasp on COM and Windows Programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to integrate/support controls (and activeX controls) in your MFC SDI application, is to derive your view class from CFormView. That will allow you to add Win32 and ActiveX controls to your form window, similar to how you did it with a dialog-based application.

When you create a new MFC SDI application, ensure the "ActiveX Controls" checkbox is checked in the Advanced Features section of the wizard. Then in the "Generated Classes" section change the base class for your view class to CFormView.

This will give you a dialog resource (for your view), which you can drag/drop Win32 or ActiveX controls onto.

Sincerely,

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Coincidentally, I did just that yesterday and it worked well as you said :)
I also tried to make my app possible to open a new popup CFormView window by clicking the menu in the frame window, but I can't open a CFormView - its constructor is `protected`. I want to open a new window that contains scroll bars.

Comment: (continued) Since CFormView subclasses CScrollView, I thought using CFormView will make it easier to use scroll bars. How can I use the CFormView as a new popup window to use scroll bars? Could you please give me any hint? Please let me know if you think this should be posted as an independent question :) Thanks.

Comment: Use MDI instead SDI.

Comment: The [`CDocTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdoctemplate-class) associates view types with documents. You merely need to register your view type for your document and everything just works. No need to call any constructors manually.

Answer (score 0):

@Ed Dore's answer works, but if you wanna do this *by code*,

declare an instance of your control's wrapper class, and
use the Create() function of it.

Now you don't need any dialog window(CDialogEx) or CFormView,

and also don't need DDX stuff.